# How to tokenize a file?

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I want to be able to analyze a local txt file I have using NLTK. By analyze, I mean use NLTK capabilities such as tokenizing, sentiment analysis etc.

I have a local file in my Python directory named 'example.txt'.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize


with open ('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        f_contents = f.readlines()
        print(word_tokenize(f_contents))
```

I am trying to print 'f_contents' in tokenized format. 'F_contents' in this case should be the text within 'example.txt'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to `word_tokenize` should be a string.

But you're feeding the output of `File.readlines()` which is a list of string.

And also when iterating through a file you are implicitly doing `File.readlines()`.

So simply:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

with open ('example.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print(word_tokenize(line))
```